# Locate Web.config for Host-named site collection in SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-config, host-named

How can I locate the web.config for a host-named site collection ?
or
Which web.config can I use for making web.config related changes for a host-named site collection ?

Answer (score 2):

All (related) host named site collections are sharing the same web.config as they are all located under a single web application (= entry within IIS).

Look into the web application list (central administration) to find the parent web application and then adapt the relevant web.config within IIS.

[image]

Please be aware that I'll have impact on all other HNSC.

Comment: for further information : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections.aspx